# Как рисовать траекторию(по которой он двигался) движения объекта в Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня имеется красный круг, который после себя должен оставлять линии, то есть траекторию по которой он двигался. Я написал небольшой скрипт и прикрепил его к нему, но что-то не работает. Помогите разобраться с проблемой.
Мой код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Траектория : MonoBehaviour
{
public Material mat;
Vector2 start, end;

void OnRenderObject()
{
    end = transform.position;
    GL.PushMatrix();
    mat.SetPass(0);
    GL.LoadOrtho();

    GL.Begin(GL.LINES);
    GL.Color(Color.red);
    GL.Vertex(start);
    GL.Vertex(end);
    GL.End();

    GL.PopMatrix();

    start = end;       
}

void Start()
{
    start = transform.position;
}
}
```

То что имеется сейчас:

[image: Броуновское движение]

То что нужно:

[image: Траектория]

Answer (score 0):

Тебя интересует Trail

Актуальная документация:

https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html